# Devise before filter that prevents access to "new_user_registration_path" unless user is signed-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise in my rails app.  My Users model is registerable, which means that anyone can go to **/users/sign_up** and create a new account.

Is it possible to protect this route, so that only signed_in users can create new accounts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a Controller with class Devise::RegistrationsController heriting. After you can add your filter. You just need define this controller like registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

In your routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}
```

Comment: @nverinaud I know it's been more than a year since you commented but, just as a heads up, you can solve that by using `authenticate_scope!` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It didn't worked for me because `authenticate_user!` is not getting called.

I fixed it that way :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :prevent_sign_up

private
    def prevent_sign_up
        redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
    end
end
```

Comment: You have a great point here, usually a standard Rails app doesn't use Devise for every action, so your solution is very valid. This is what worked for me.