# Rails Devise: How will the Admin be able to Edit other users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I saw this [Rails Devise: How to access sign up page after signed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545166/rails-devise-how-to-access-sign-up-page-after-signed-in) and it worked. Now I want to know how to allow Admin to edit some Users. Any inputs? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I didn't create any models for the admin since I migrated an admin:boolean inside the User model. And no need for cancancan. See how I use the admin:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
   <!-- do something only the admin is allowed to do-->
<% else %>
   <!-- do something by user that can also be done by the admin-->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Admin and User are separate models?

Comment: nope. I didn't have to create any models. I just added an admin:boolean to my User model (via migration).

Comment: Just follow normal procedure, create custom page, allow admin to edit some users and call update action on it.

Comment: I asked the wrong question. Sorry. But thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

You have to divide two concepts: auhtentication and authorization. Authentication is when your app tells: "Oh, I know this user, I've seen him before, because I know his email. It was here, somewhere in my User table in the db". Authorization is to give your user rights to do something or deny access on some action.

Devise - is a great gem for *authentication* (registering users, sign_in/sign/out, sessions, passwords and so on). Devise has no *authorizational* features.

So, you have two ways: 1) code authorization system by yourself, or 2) use the authorizational gems. Here are great gem for authorization that fit with Devise very well: [Cancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) from it's author.

Comment: I asked the wrong question. Sorry. Thank you for this! But since my Admin is boolean, I don't need cancan. The regular Users function is to login/logout only. The rest (CRUD of users), is on the hands of the Admin.

Comment: The way your define your Admin (separate model, boolean value, string/symbol value, role, etc.) is absolutely unrelated with restricted/permitted actions. Cancan doesn't assign/define user role but user abilities to do or not to do something.
Anyway, will it be cancan or not, you have to implement this algorithm: 1) check if the current_user is admin; 2) define method based at the logical condition "turn current_user away UNLESS current_user is an admin"; 3) use this method in your UsersController (in your case on every action except :index, :show, :new, :create).

Comment: Except, i wouln't recommend cancan, as it is not supported for about a year. Use it's successor `cancancan` or `pundit`

Comment: Yes, I gave link to "cancancan" repo, but mistyped the name.