# Rails Devise, how to make "sign up" only for superuser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise for Rails 3.2.1 app. I want to block the sign_up so that only a superuser/administrator can add new users. How do i achieve that?

(Update) I tried the tip suggested in [Devise before filter that prevents access to "new_user_registration_path" unless user is signed-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213006/devise-before-filter-that-prevents-access-to-new-user-registration-path-unless)

but it does not work, since the added controller is apparently not password-protecting the new route "/users/registrations":

> Create a Controller with class Devise::RegistrationsController
>   heriting. After you can add your filter. You just need define this
>   controller like registration controller
>
> ```
> class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
>   before_filter :authenticate_user!
> end
> ```
>
> In your routes.rb
>
> ```
> devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you create a CRUD only available to the super user and he will be able to create users instead of restricting access to the registration path to only the super user. You can find help for it here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface.

In case you want to use the registration, I would do almost the same you put on your answer but the before_filter should be something like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :redirect_unless_admin

# (...)

private
def redirect_unless_admin
  unless current_user.admin        
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution from Tony Amoyal
I tested and it works like a charm...

 http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

He uses cancan, but the hooks are easily customized for other mechanisms.
copied here to future reference if his blog gets broken:

..."you want to protect user registrations. This requires us to use CanCan to check for permissions but customize the Devise Registrations controller to restrict access.

One way to do this is to copy the devise controllers into your controllers directory and start customizing. That may be the best way to go and it’s certainly an obvious path, but all I want to do restrict registration. Should I really have to re-implement the registrations controller to do that? For now, I will not. It might make sense when there are more customizations. Instead I inherit from the Devise Registrations controller. Here are the steps:

Step 1 – Create the controller

```
$ mkdir app/controllers/users
$ touch app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
```

Step 2 – Add the custom functionality

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :check_permissions, :only => [:new, :create, :cancel]
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
  end
end
```

The check permissions method is really simple. It calls the CanCan method, authorize!, and checks if the current user can create users. We use resource here because devise uses resource to refer to the model that can be authenticated. Also notice how I removed the require_no_authentication filter, a Devise filter which allows access to actions without authentication."