# How to make devise RegistrationsController to show sign_up page only if user is already signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I tried to find solution by google and here in SO but couldn't found...
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213006/devise-before-filter-that-prevents-access-to-new-user-registration-path-unless) is the only question. It has only one answer and it's accepted but doesn't work for me... Here is my code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    puts "Method new was called"
    super
  end

end
```

When I'm not logged in at `localhost:3000/sign_up` page is displayed normally and `Method new was called` is printed. I want controller to redirect me into sign_in page if I'm not already signed in. Of course I can check it in `new` method and redirect but it's not a good solution... I'm sure there is a more elegant way. I even tried to use `prepend_before_filter :authenticate_user!` but it doesn't work too.

**EDIT**

I've defined routes for this controller in routs.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Comment: Have you define this controller class in your devise route ?

Comment: yes of course. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Devise::RegistrationsController` has [require_no_authentication before filter](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L2) by default.

So it's needed to skip it:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    puts "Method new was called"
    super
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

does not work any more.

Use `authenticate_scope!` instead.