# Only allow admin to create new admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

My blog has a devise model called `Admin`.

I definitely don't want that visitors of my website can register as an admin. So I did the following:

In my `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

After that I created a new `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
end
```

But when I visit my `my.site/admins/sign_up` as a "normal visitor" the `authenticate_admin!` hook is not called - so I get a full working registration form. Why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799593/how-to-make-devise-registrationscontroller-to-show-sign-up-page-only-if-user-is) may help. To summarize, Devise's RegistrationsController [skips authentication by default](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L2):

```
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
```

So, skip it and your before_action should work:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication
  before_action :authenticate_scope!
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost worked for me. As Lamp pointed out beneath the accepted answer in your linked question I had to replace `authenticate_admin!` with `authenticate_scope!`. If you change your answer to this I can accept it.